# Why does my Visual Studio 2019 solution open with Solution Explorer closed?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I've used lots of other versions of Visual Studio. Currently, I work with Visual Studio 2019.

I always PIN the Solution Explorer window open, like so:

[image: Solution Explorer pinned open]

However, whenever I re-open a solution or after debugging a solution, the Solution Explorer window is always closed, like shown below:

[image: Solution Explorer closed]

Why does my Solution Explorer window keep closing, and how to I stop this behavior?

Comment: Possibly relevant from [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/51581/solution-explorer-does-not-remain-pinned-after-clo.html): "*if a tool window is pinned in the same group as Solution Explorer, and you have elected to auto-hide that tool window on startup to prevent it from slowing VS down, and that window is on top when you close VS, on next boot, because the window needs to reappear on top of the group, VS will unpin the group to prevent the startup impact*".

Comment: @dxiv - I don't *think* I have elected to auto-hide the tool window - unless I did that by mistake. The link you provided is a Read-Only solution. Where would that tool window setting be found? That's probably what I need.

Comment: Team Explorer seems to be in the same group, is it set to auto-hide? Also check Help / Visual Studio Performance Manager / Tool Windows.

Comment: @dxiv - **Tool Windows > Team Explorer** was set to `Auto hide window at startup`. You're the Man! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion by [dxiv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5538420) in a comment, I solved this by the Visual Studio 2019 menu:

- Help
- Visual Studio Performance Manager
- Tool Windows
- Disable Auto Hide

After I disabled Auto Hide, it no longer appears in the dialog box on my PC.

[image: Screenshot]